# Android Studio 2 update not inside current program

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

I've got an issue with Android Studio: when there is an update and I want to install it in my Android Studio I must use web-link to get newest version. After I download it I got NEW Android Studio program in my computer, which I can run using `android-studio/bin/studio64.exe`. This is weird, cause I want to have update in Android Studio - which means initial update build-in my current Android Studio program`.

P.S. Website is something like this:

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/

or this:

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest.

I can only download it. Cannot update it via Android Studio...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can update from within the IDE, but this is a preview version and somethings things go wrong, which was the case here:

> Due to a bug, you can only patch from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2, 3, 4 and 5. All other versions will need to download a complete install of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with major updates of AndroidStudio, that's correct. Only minor updates can be updated from inside the studio.

First, make sure you know where your SDK lays. I'm just assuming the path to your studio installation is `C:\Programs\android-studio`

If your SDK is located in `C:\Programs\android-studio\sdk` (which it shouldn't be in newer versions), you have to copy that to any other location.

After that, rename your folder `android-studio` to something like `android-studio_OLD`. Then, copy the new version of android studio to your location (`C:\Programs\android-studio`).

Then you can try if it starts if you start `C:\Programs\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe`.

(Note: If you had your SDK inside your studio folder, you might have to enter the path to the new folder of your SDK for everything to work properly)

If the Studio is up and running as it should, you can delete `android-studio_OLD`.